# How can I view transfer log information for Exchange 2010?

Tags: exchange, smtp

We're running an Exchange 2010 server in an Active Directory environment.

It has no problem sending emails to 99% of recipients.  However there are some who get a bounce and error:

```
#550 4.4.7 QUEUE.Expired; message expired ##
```

I seem to be able to telnet to the recipient server and manually use SMTP.  I attempted the Exchange Troubleshooting Assistant, but came up with nothing.

So I have two questions:

1. How do I view log data about message transactions?  I want to see what commands our exchange server executed and what responses it received.
2. Any ideas as to what might cause some messages to expire, while most seem to work fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here: http://exchangeserverpro.com/exchange-server-protocol-logging/

Basically you just need to enable SMTP protocol logging to allow you to debug the commands being sent/received.